# until it takes its due -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

Example ([Putin Would Eat President Trump for Lunch](http://www.bloombergview.com/articles/2015-07-31/putin-would-eat-trump-for-lunch?cmpid=yhoo)):

> Topless photos and macho adventures aside, Putin is no showman. He's a colorless career bureaucrat with the steely core of a KGB man. The popularity he enjoys is nothing like stardom: It's a mixture of fear, love and submission. Putin doesn't do deals, as Trump does, or as Berezovsky and Chichvarkin once did, because he has never been a businessman. Putin is a man of the state. And the state can't be gamed or beaten. No deal is ever final **until it takes its due**.

How do you understand that phrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the State doesn't have to bargain or negotiate what it gets out of a transaction: it takes what it is *due* (owed) off the top, by fiat not by contract, and leaves the contracting parties to sort out how to split up what's left over.

As a famous social analyst once put it, "Render unto Caesar what is Caesar's". Putin, says the author, is the heir of the Caesars and their namesakes the Tsars.

Comment: Makes sense... except.....why say the **deal** takes its due?  Isn't it the strongman/autocrat who takes **his** due?  Could it be that the deal _takes its due course_ (during which the crafty/strong party takes _his due_ portion/reward)?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock *It* is the State, not the deal. That can be perfectly clear in speech, where *beaten* will take a half cadence (I'd point it with a colon), and *it* would be contrastively stressed.